# JavaScript code to recursively parse it and print all the IDs in console

Tags: javascript

I am trying print out all the ids using javascript , but I do not how to do it pls anybody help me. Below is the question?

Consider following javascript object:

```
var obj =[{

  id: "A", 
  children:[{    
  id: "B",
    children: [{
      id: "C",
      children: [{
        id: "D",
        children: [{
          id: "E",
          children: [{
            id: "F"
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        id: "G",
        children: {
          id: "H"
        }
      }]
    }, {
      id: "I"
    }]
  }, {
    id: "J",
    children: [{
      id: "K"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  id: "L"
}, {
  id: "M",
  children: {
    id: "N",
    children: [{
      id: "O"
    }]
  }
}, {
  id: "P"
}];
```

JavaScript code  to recursively parse it and print all the IDs in console so that the output looks like:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
```

Comment: console.log and loop. Google it

Comment: @mvc_help  i tried it , and i am fresher in java script .. and learning JSON.

Comment: @mvc_help var recu = '';

function scan(obj)
{
    var k;
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        for (k in obj){
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)){
                //body += 'scanning property ' + k + '<br/>';
                scan( obj[k] );  
            }                
        }
    } else {
        recu += ' ' + obj + '<br/>';
    };
  
};

scan(obj);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = recu;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are a newbie, I can just give you a hint, so that you can actually start thinking.

`typeof` can give you the type of a variable, and `Object.keys(<ObjName>)` can give you list of keys for an object.

Think if you can use this to do Breadth First Search or a Depth First Search.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = [{id: "A", children:[{id: "B", children: [{ id: "C", children: [{ id: "D", children: [{ id: "E", children: [{ id: "F" }] }] }, { id: "G", children: { id: "H" } }] }, { id: "I" }] }, { id: "J", children: [{ id: "K" }] }] }, { id: "L" }, { id: "M", children: { id: "N", children: [{ id: "O" }] } }, { id: "P" }];

const printIds = (object) => {
  Object.keys(object).forEach(k => {
    return typeof object[k] === 'object'
      ? printIds(object[k])
      : k === 'id' ? console.log(object[k]) : null
  })
}

printIds(obj)
```